# Why is the eDisMax parser not inserting into QueryResult Cache?

Tags: search, solr, lucene

Our team does product search and we have extensive use for using [eDisMax parser](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Extended+DisMax+Query+Parser). We have been tuning our Solr caching and we found Query results cache is not getting insert when we use EDisMax parser. We do have handler which uses dismax parser and that populates query result cache.

Not we do not have query having NOW in our query. Using Solr 4.10.2

Comment: Do you have an example of a query that doesn't get cached?

Comment: path=/bbselect params={indent=true&q=*:*&debug=true&wt=json}. this is a basic query.

Comment: q=ipad&timeAllowed=1000&defType=edismax&fl=skuid&start=0&rows=15&facet.limit=9999&enableElevation=true&enableSynonym=true&query.boost=true&debugQuery=true&debug.explain.structured=true&fq=!sku_emergency_delete:1&facet=true&facet.mincount=1&facet.threads=32&facet.field=dynamiccategory_facet&facet.field=soldby_facet&f.soldby_facet.facet.sort=count&facet.query=currentprice_facet:[0 TO 49.99]&facet.query=currentprice_facet:[50 TO 99.99]&f.currentprice_facet.facet.sort=count&facet.recommend.maxfacets=20&qt=/bbselect